# Return results when row not matched in join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some tables that look like the following:

Table 1:

```
ID | Email
```

Table 2:

```
Email_ID | Note
```

Table 3:

```
Email_ID | URL
```

How would one go about producing a set of results where all rows in table 1 are produced long with fields from table 2 and 3 where available. Note that not all emails are in tables 2 and 3 but I would still want these results.

Comment: Is it for mysql or postgresql? PS: `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: It is postgresql. Sorry for the basic question I'm just working through some basic problems and this is my first time working without Django database models.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1
       LEFT JOIN
       Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.Email_ID
       LEFT JOIN
       Table3 ON Table1.ID=Table3.Email_ID
```